# How to animate xib constraints inside a view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xib, uiviewanimation

I've built a counter that animates when you swipe up or down.

So basically it's a Circular UIView inside a view controller that I animate

by increasing the offset when the  user swipes up or down.

It works perfectly, but now I'm trying to put it in a .Xib file and then

load the Nib on the view controller.

and It's not working, only the label is getting animated but not the

circular view.

How can I animate the xib inside the view

here is my code :

````

```
func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

   // up or down
   if sender.direction == .Up {
    increment = 1
    offset = 10
   } else {
    increment = -1
    offset = -10
   }

  // animate stuff with constraints
  inc(increment)

  UIView.animateWithDuration(0.18, animations: { _ in

    self.labelYConstraint.constant = self.offset
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.label.alpha = 1
    self.label.textColor = UIColor(red: 52/255.0, green: 52/255.0, blue: 88/255.0, alpha: 1)
    self.circleView.filledColor = UIColor(red: 167/255.0, green: 246/255.0, blue: 67/255.0, alpha: 1)
  }
  }) { _ in

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.18, animations: { _ in
      self.labelYConstraint.constant = 0
      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
      self.circleView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 211/255.0, green: 211/255.0, blue: 211/255.0, alpha: 0.3).CGColor
      self.label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    })
 }
}
```

````

The first button is a UIView animated

The second button is a .Xib file embeded in the view controller

[image]

Comment: The words "animate a xib" are completely meaningless.

Comment: How would you reformulate the question ? I know a xib is a view, I just wanted to make the question explicit.

Comment: A xib is not a view. It is a xib (a nib file).

Comment: Would it be better to say: how to animate xib components or xib constraints ?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be animating the Y constraint for the label. You must make sure you animate a constraint that sets the position for the whole group.

An easy way would be, in the xib, to create a transparent subview and put all the elements inside, and create a Y constraint to position that subview in the main xib view. When you animate that new constraint, it should move all the elements together.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Tks, I will try it out and I'll let you know. How come it works for the first view animation. I only animate the label's Y constraint and the whole group gets animated.

Comment: The constraints specify how each element react to changes in each other's positions. So I'm guessing that in the first case, the constraints are different and they connect the other element's positions to the label's position. Just look at the constraints on both cases and see what is different, experiment with that a bit :)

Comment: After some trials and errors I managed to find the solution. If I animate ( view.frame.origin.y ) I get the desired result. :)